# How can I force unmounting when I get permission denied even as root user

Tags: command-line, permissions, mount

I was playing around with the mount command to understand what it does. I tried mounting my iphone on my laptop. I followed advice online which I can't seem to find anymore, and I'm not sure about the exact steps I took. In any case, I now have a directory called `012ce47b174c336ac8854ccf14d5df020b15717e` my `media` folder. When I `cd` into media and run `ls`, I get this (logged into my user account):

`ls: cannot access '012ce47b174c336ac8854ccf14d5df020b15717e': Input/output error`

`012ce47b174c336ac8854ccf14d5df020b15717e  another_directory`

I then tried `rm -rf 012ce47b174c336ac8854ccf14d5df020b15717e` and I got:

`rm: cannot remove '012ce47b174c336ac8854ccf14d5df020b15717e': Is a directory`

So I logged into the root account and tried the same things, and got the exact same results. So what should I do?

Comment: To unmount a volume on Ubuntu, please use `umount` not `rm`. Please read: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/umount.8.html

Comment: Thanks this helped

Comment: I am glad it helped.